# Problem with Mocha test when try to use the 'return' in the function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am learning the Mocha test for js but have a weird problem an couldn't figure it out. Any big man can help me:

I do this test case:

```
it("remove all the number larger than 10", () => {
      function filter(arr) {
        return arr.filter(number => number < 11);
      }

      assert.equal(filter([1, 3, 3, 5, 10, 29, 3], [1, 3, 3, 5, 10, 3]));
    });
```

But it returns undefined for that filter function, but when I remove the return keyword, it works fine:

```
it("remove all the number larger than 10", () => {
      function filter(arr) {
        arr.filter(number => number < 11);
      }

      assert.equal(filter([1, 3, 3, 5, 10, 29, 3], [1, 3, 3, 5, 10, 3]));
    });
```

Can anyone can explain it to me? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a typo, your close paren `)` for `filter` should be immediately after the first array instead of after both arrays.

Also, to compare arrays use [`assert.deepEqual`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_deepequal) instead of `assert.equal`:

```
it("remove all the number larger than 10", () => {
  function filter(arr) {
    return arr.filter(number => number < 11);
  }

  assert.deepEqual(filter([1, 3, 3, 5, 10, 29, 3]), [1, 3, 3, 5, 10, 3]);  // SUCCESS
});
```

---

(The reason why it was passing when you removed the `return` keyword is that `filter` was being passed both arrays, then returning `undefined`.  `assert.equal` was only being called with one argument so its second argument was implicitly `undefined`.  Since `undefined` == `undefined` your test passed.)